# Detect whether bot is using voice: RequestAttribute is null

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57201475/how-to-know-if-the-bot-is-using-voice-or-text-in-lex), the `requestAttributes` property of `lexEvent` can be checked to determine whether an incoming request supports voice.

However, in my C# Lambda, that property is null:

```
public LexResponse FunctionHandler(LexEvent lexEvent, ILambdaContext context)
{
    LambdaLogger.Log($"Request Populated: {lexEvent.RequestAttributes != null}");
```

Logged:

```
2020-08-20 18:03:04: START RequestId: f363e694-77e4-40fe-b607-ddaf51b6852f Version: $LATEST
2020-08-20 18:03:04: Request Populated: False
```

How, in the context of the C# developer's kit, can I determine whether the request my lambda is processing is voice or text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Lambda Input Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html#using-lambda-input-event-format) includes `outputDialogMode`:

```
"outputDialogMode": "Text or Voice, based on ContentType request header in runtime API request",
```

The AWS document further explains:

> **outputDialogMode** – For each user input, the client sends the request to Amazon Lex using one of the runtime API operations, PostContent or PostText. Amazon Lex uses the request parameters to determine whether the response to the client is text or voice, and sets this field accordingly.
>
> The Lambda function can use this information to generate an appropriate message. For example, if the client expects a voice response, your Lambda function could return Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML) instead of text.

So your Lambda function should be able to check `lexEvent.outputDialogMode` as either "Voice" or "Text" and then you can respond appropriately based on that.

Comment: For some reason it seems this is not set by AWS Connect when invoking Lex... Any ideas?

Comment: @Michał You could set it up yourself using session attributes ("contact attributes" in Connect) when invoking Lex and pass your own Voice/Text attribute and then detect it in Lambda. That's what I had to do before we had this new outputDialogMode.